# RTSP proxy/pipe to another server

Tags: php, http, proxy, streaming, rtsp

I saw a question similar however the answers were irelevant to what I'm trying to achieve. Given that I have a local media server (for example Wowza) how can I use another server to pipe the requests to my local wowza server?

I'll expand. Given I have an application which sends live video feed to a webserver which runs apache server I'm looking for a script (prefebly `php`) to recieve this data and send it to another server which has wowza. (so basically act like a proxy)

**ADVANCED:**
I was also looking for a little more advanced solution if possible. If I open the webserver (send a request) I want it to start sending data to my local wowza server given it knows the right port